# Ordered associative arrays in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I can do the following in `bash`:

```
declare -A data
data[A]="aaa"
data[C]="ccc"
data[B]="bbb"

for i in "${!data[@]}" ; do
    printf "%-20s ---> %s\n" "$i" "${data[$i]}"
done
```

Which outputs:

```
A                    ---> aaa
B                    ---> bbb
C                    ---> ccc
```

That is, the associative array is reordered (I assume using lexicographic ordering on the keys, but I am not sure), and loses the original order in which I created the data. I wanted instead:

```
A                    ---> aaa
C                    ---> ccc
B                    ---> bbb
```

In `python` I would use an `OrderedDict` instead of a plain `dict` for that. Is there a similar concept in bash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already answered, associative arrays are not ordered. If you want ordering in that array, use below work-around.

```
declare -A data
data_indices=()
data[A]="aaa"; data_indices+=(A)
data[C]="ccc"; data_indices+=(C)
data[B]="bbb"; data_indices+=(B)

for i in "${data_indices[@]}" ; do
    printf "%-20s ---> %s\n" "$i" "${data[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: Thx. Interesting hack. A pity that bash does not allow for a more elegant construct.

Comment: Why pity? Associative arrays are not meant to be ordered, in any language.

Comment: Worrying about the lack of data structures available in `bash` is a sure sign that your program should no longer be written in `bash`. It's a glue language for running other programs, not a data-processing language.

Comment: @anishsane: call it whatever you like, ordered dictionaries are *useful*. As I have just learned, bash does not have them, and that is a pity.

Comment: @chepner: I have this *very simple* script: I use an associative array to map command names to script functions. It is just a kind of menu. And it works fine. But because of the lack of ordered associative arrays, the help (a dump of the associative array) is completely out or order, which confuses me all the time. I could do this in python, but I would just be doing `subprocess.call` for all commands, which is much easier and cleanly implemented in bash. And anyway, the commands are just running system tools. So that is a use case where a simple ordered associative array would help.

Comment: @chepner: another good option would be to implement my menu in a makefile, but I do not like this because makefiles are less powerful than bash scripts (you can do it, but the syntax is horrible: `; \` everywhere)

Answer (score 1):

There is no defined ordering of associative arrays in Bash. The ordering of output from your script will therefore be unpredictable. If you want to store more information in your array, I would suggest to create another parallel associative array that would use same keys.